# Does using LDRSH in ARM overwrite the register if there is value from the 16..32 bit?

Tags: binary, arm, hex

One example I was given was say let's say

```
R0=0000 A000 H
R3=0000 0040 H
R2=0044 100A H

Assume in the byte addressable memory locations (little endian)
(0000 A080)=> 66
(0000 A081)=>11

LDRSH R2,[R0,R3,LSL #1]
```

What is the content of R2?

So

`R0, R3,LSL #1`  is `0000 A080` so we access the memory and take a halfword since SH

and replace it on the lower end of register since its little endian format

so it should be  `R2= 0044 1166 H`, but I'm confused with the sign extension, does it overwrite the `0044` with zero since the most significant bit of the half word is 0? Because I remember the answer given in class being `R2=0044 1166 H` but I'm assuming it should be `R2=0000 1166 H`, maybe I saw it wrong.

Also just to make sure, what happens if instead 11 in the memory `(0000 A081)` it was `CD` ,would the sign be extended with 1 and overwrite the `0044` part too?

or do we only take into consideration the Halfword we changed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it overwrites the entire register.  The value in R2 will be `00001166H` in your first example, and `FFFFCD66H` in your second.

That's the point of sign extension - you get the 32-bit value that represents the same signed integer as your 16-bit value.  That value is "four thousand four hundred fifty-four" in the first example, and "negative twelve thousand nine hundred fifty-four" in the second.  It's particularly important on ARM because all the arithmetic is 32 bits.

I think either your instructor made a mistake, or you copied or remembered it incorrectly.